# How can i display markers based on some filters using google maps api in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Basically my problem is that i need to filter the markers that are currently displayed on the map(there's like 7 of them), but to do that i need to refresh the page(the map component) because there i do the requirement check(fiter check) in this case the price, and i need to readd the markers that meet the requirement. When the map first loads it dispays all the markers from the db.

I tried using new window.google.maps.reload(); after the button was pressed and this.forceUpdate() but can't figure out the logic

```
return (
  <div>
          <MenuItem
            eventKey={3.1}
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ price: 2 });
              new window.google.maps.reload();
            }}
          >
            Budget
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem
            eventKey={3.2}
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ price: 3 });
              new window.google.maps.reload();
            }}
          >
            Expensive
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem
            eventKey={3.3}
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ price: 4 });
              new window.google.maps.reload();
            }}
          >
            Luxury
          </MenuItem>
        </DropdownButton>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
    <Map
      id="myMap"
      options={{
        center: { lat: 44.439663, lng: 26.096306 },
        zoom: 12
      }}
      onMapLoad={map => {
        if (this.state.price === 2) {
          this.state.restaurants.map(restaurant => {
            if (restaurant.price === 2) {
              addMarker(restaurant, map);
            }
          });
        } else {
          this.state.restaurants.map(restaurant =>
            addMarker(restaurant, map)
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

}
}

export default App;

Comment: What library are you using for the Map ?

Comment: I'm not using any library, map component can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/97s54jQL and here is the full code from the initial post: https://pastebin.com/wZREKVGE

Comment: one quick hack cane be using a key in your Map component by forcing it to be re-created every time the key changes:

    <Map
      id="myMap"
      key={this.state.price}
      options={{
        center: { lat: 44.439663, lng: 26.096306 },
        zoom: 12
      }}
      ...

    />

Comment: It worked!!! Next i'll try to add different filters types(Like a rating, price etc.), is it a good idea to continue doing this hack using the key? Also flodding the map component props area with if else statements like i did with price? How would you do it? Thanks a lot for the answer!!

Comment: I haven't looked much into the google maps api, but I would probably add a `componentDidUpdate` method in the Map component and update my map when I receive new props there instead of using keys. Also you can probably move your inline onMapLoad method to a component method `onMapLoad={this.onMapLoad}`

Comment: this article from a quick google search might be helpful: https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/